# How to create custom "rename" dialog for my type of resource in Eclipse (basic refactoring)?

Tags: eclipse

How to create custom "rename" dialog for my type of resource in Eclipse (basic refactoring)?

I'm using eclipse to open certain types of files (not java) in custom GEF editor.

Now I want to do some extra job if file is renamed (update referenced to it if user wants etc.). I want to use custom "rename" dialog and add several "checkboxes" there (like [x] update reference1, [x] update reference2, [x] do other extra job)

I.e. I need something like that, but for my own type of resources:
[image: exmple]

Thanks

Comment: What are you asking for exactly?

How to write a dialog?

Or how to run your job after the OK button is pressed?

The dialog in the question is an instance of RefactoringWizardDialog2, which is internal to Eclipse. So you can't really extend this.

You'd have to decide to either write your own Dialog, or decide that what you want is a Wizard, and write your own Wizard and Wizard pages.
If you take the 2nd option you'd have to write a Runnable to do the work once OK is pressed.

Happy to provide more info if you clarify your question...

Comment: well it's easy to write a dialog or a wizard, how to force Eclipse to replace standard "rename resource dialog" with my custom one?

Comment: I wish to do exactly the same. Unfortunately there's no chance. Maybe one way would be to register one's own file type in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems LTK doesn't allow to change UI of rename dialog. It's only possible to add custom pre/post changes, more information can be found in this thread http://www.mail-archive.com/rubyeclipse-development@lists.sourceforge.net/msg00517.html